# Clojure: Compojure and friend, interactive form: empty params

Tags: authentication, clojure, compojure

I'm trying to create server authentication on a Compojure server, authenticating with friend.
Setup and routing seems to work fine; when I visit the `/manage` route, I get redirected to `/login` and can enter my data; but after entering user/pass I get redirected to `/login?authentication_failed=Y&username=`.

Adding some logging showed me that the `:credential-fn` gets passed the empty string for username and password, and redirecting and intercepting the POST request shows me that params and query string are always empty, and username or password keys don't appear anywhere.

I'm working from a `lein new www <name>` project where I updated the dependencies to their latest versions (and inluded the lates friend dep, of course). There is no `-main` yet, I'm just running it with `lein ring server`.

Can someone help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

handler.clj

```
(ns authme.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]
            [ring.util.response :as resp]
            [cemerick.friend :as friend]
            [cemerick.friend.credentials :as creds]
            [cemerick.friend.workflows :as workflows]
            [authme.loginpage :refer [login login-form]]
            [hiccup.page :refer [html5]]))

(def users {"usr" {:username "usr"
                   :password (creds/hash-bcrypt "test")
                   :roles #{::admin}}})

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" request
       (html5 [:a {:href "/manage"} "Manage resources"]))
  (GET "/manage" request 
       (friend/authenticated "Admin-page")) ;; also tried authorize as admin
  (GET "/login" request
       (html5
        (if-let [query (request :query-string)]
          (do (println query)
              (html5 [:div [:h2 query [:br]]
                      login-form]))
          login-form)))
  (POST "/echo" request
        (let [req-lines (clojure.string/join \newline request)]
          (println req-lines)
          ;; ugly code just to print the map without using brains
          (html5 [:ul (map #(identity [:li [:b (first %) ": "] (or (second %) "-- empty --")])
                           request)])))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (friend/authenticate app-routes
                       {:credential-fn (fn [sign-in-info]
                                         (prn "--sign in:" sign-in-info)
                                         (creds/bcrypt-credential-fn users sign-in-info))
                        :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]}))
```

And the forms (loginpage.clj)

```
(ns authme.loginpage)

;; my own login field
(defn login []
  [:form {:action "login"
          :method "POST"}
   [:div
    [:label "Username"]
    [:input {:type "text" :name "username" :required true}]] [:br]
   [:div [:label "Password"]
    [:input {:type "password"  :name "password" :required true}]] [:br]
   [:input {:type "submit" :name "submit" :value "Login"}]])

;; copy-paste from friend-demos
(def login-form
  [:div {:class "row"}
   [:div {:class "columns small-12"}
    [:h3 "Login"]
    [:div {:class "row"}
     [:form {:method "POST" :action "echo" :class "columns small-4"} ;; intercept the request for debugging
      [:div "Username" [:input {:type "text" :name "username"}]]
      [:div "Password" [:input {:type "password" :name "password"}]]
      [:div [:input {:type "submit" :class "button" :value "Login"}]]]]]])
```

Comment: Adding the `wrap-params` middleware before the authenticate step will cause the POST /echo route to receive params, still the :credential-fn will get two empty strings

Comment: Didn't you forget `wrap-keyword-params`?